# I am trying to evaluate double integral on octave

Tags: octave, numerical-integration

So I have need to evaluate double integral on octave[![question][1]][1]

```
>> x1 = 1;
>> x2 = 0;
>> y1 = 2;
>> y2 = 0;
>> f = @(x,y) (y-x)./((x+y).^3);
>> integral2(f,x2,x1,y2,y1);
```

I entered the above code but it gives me error: "Maximum number of sub-tiles reached, accuracy may be low" and gives NAN as answer. Any solutions?
This is the integral I need to evaluate: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xv5AM.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function `f` for your integrand:

`f = @(x,y) (y-x)./(x+y).^3`

Note the element-wise `./` and `.^` functions to avoid matrix operations. Now use the `dblquad` function:

`dblquad(f,0,2,0,1)`

where those last four input arguments are your integration limits for `x` and `y`. You can also specify a different tolerance and an integrator function with additional input arguments, but the defaults work fine in this case. I obtained the answer you were expecting with this method.

For a single-line operation, you can skip creating the integrand function by using

`dblquad( @(x,y) (y-x)./(x+y).^3 , 0 , 2 , 0 , 1 )`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the function evaluated at 0,0 returns NaN.

Which raises the question, how would you like 0,0 to be treated?

The limit seems to be zero, so you could try excluding it up to numerical precision.

The following:

```
a = integral2(f,x2+eps,x1,y2+eps,y1, 'method', 'iterated');
```

worked for me, but interpretation of this result is up to you ...

Comment: okay so now it is giving me 0.1667 as answer but actual answer is 0.333333